# Segmentation Fault

Tags: arrays, c, string, segmentation-fault

i want to find the Length of a String without Using strlen() function.
but it gives me segmentation fault error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned string_length(char str[])
{
  int i;
  printf("Enter a string:");
  scanf("%s",&str);
  for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0';++i)
  {
  }
  printf("Length of string: %d", i);
  return i;
}
int main()
{
  int ausgabe;
  char str[100];
  ausgabe = string_length(str[100]);
  return 0;
}
```

This is what i did, i have tried with all possible variations (all i know (while, for, even with if))
but non of them seem to be the answer to my problem.
*I am new to programming and would welcome advice from professionals*

Comment: What do you think `string_length(str[100])` does?

Comment: It works if you fix your pointers: https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZBLTsMwEIbF1qcYgqomakHuDhHSXXfcAKLKtR1npDJBfqyqnqSbbHopToOdB5SV7W_Gn_6Zy1XujZR9fw2-eXz-vqsekOQxKA2vzivsntotu0UWySTGAjk0pBWMbH_UZHyby1bYhN7rgp0YAJIHLOPlK3b5Js925LUFMX17yYpUdFJQrC1cto58QE1nIUeogJeDD2u4r2D5wZflaoVF7Ej68435bUgAXTO7YaGyNeCgs9oHSynKmaVMnwIp_4sogjPioFPn7wQbzusEplqM8n_UOemk5lE9brGfD3GQSo-PHw

Comment: The name of the array ```str``` is a pointer to the first element of the array, which satisfies ```scanf's``` requirement. You do not need that ampersand before ```scanf```.

Comment: @axmed777,  Save time and **enable all compiler warnings** to quickly see trouble, like with `scanf("%s",&str);` and `string_length(str[100])`.

Comment: The first thing to do is fix your type errors that your compiler warned you about.  You're passing a `char` argument to a function that expects a `char *`.  Of course that won't work, just as your compiler told you.  As long as you're getting warnings you don't understand, do *not* try to run your code, and do *not* worry about functionality.  Understand and correct the warnings first.  Hint:  If a function expects a `char *`, or a `char  []`, argument, then you must pass it a `char *`, not a `char`.  The title of your post should not have mentioned your warning, not the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to pass &str to scanf("%s",&str); only pass str (without reference operator) to scanf. Also, the better way to create a function is like following (see input parameters of string_length function):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned string_length(char str[])
{
  int i;
  //printf("Enter a string:");
  //scanf("%s",&str);
  for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0';++i)
          ;
  //printf("Length of string: %d", i);
  return i;
}
int main()
{
  int ausgabe;
  char str[100];
  printf("%s", "Enter a string:");
  scanf("%s",str);
  ausgabe = string_length(str);
  printf("Length of string: %d\n", ausgabe);

  return 0;
}
```